# swap adjacent input characters in a given list, in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, swap

Given the declaration of the swapIfAdjacent function I need to do the following:

```
swapIfAdjacent :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
```

If either a,b or b,a are consecutive items, then for the first and only occurrence the order of these two items should be swapped.

My code so far:

```
swapIfAdjacent _ _ [] = []
swapIfAdjacent a b (x:xs) | a `elem` xs && b `elem` xs
                          = if adjacent a b xs then swap a b (x:xs) else (x:xs) 
                          | otherwise = error "not adjacent"   
                             where
                             swap _ _ [] = []
                             swap a b (x:xs) 
                                 |    a == x = b : swap a b xs
                                 |    b == x = a : swap a b xs
                                 | otherwise = x : swap a b xs
```

The adjacent function that I'm using is already defined as follows:

```
adjacent :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> Bool
adjacent a b (x:y:etc)  |  x == a
                        =  y == b
                        |  x == b
                        =  y == a
                        |  otherwise
                        =  adjacent a b (y:etc)
adjacent _ _ _          =  False
```

I have observed that according to my implementation the swapping procedure occurs for every element and not only for the first ones and also the following error:

```
swapIfAdjacent 'a' 'a' "banana" --> banana
```

while

```
swapIfAdjacent 'b' 'b' "banana" --> error "not adjacent"
```

Both of the above examples should produce as output the whole list and not errors. I assume the error has to do with the fact that 'b' is appearing in the list only once "banana" while 'a' multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a lot of unnecessary work here. Here's an implementation to consider.

```
swapIfAdjacent a b (x:y:xys) | (a, b) == (x, y) || (b, a) == (x, y) = y:x:xys
                             | otherwise = x : swapIfAdjacent a b (y:xys)
swapIfAdjacent _ _ xys = xys
```

You don't need any of `elem`, `adjacent` or `swap`.

Comment: nice‌​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍

Comment: Your implementation help me a lot to understand how this function works. I'm new to Haskell and many times I'm thinking more complicated than I should be.